# What do I name the file to create a category for NSString?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

My interface, for example, looks like this:

```
@interface NSString (CategoryName)
```

And then this for implementation--

```
@implementation NSString (CategoryName)
```

But what do I actually call the files? NSString.m/.h ? Does it matter?

Comment: The convention I've seen is to use the name of the class and the name of the category separated by a plus sign: NSString+CategoryName.h/.m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's entirely up to you.

However, the [convention](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Category_Names) is to name them like this.

> NSString+CategoryName.h
>
> NSString+CategoryName.m